# Center a Grid in qml in a scroolview qml

Tags: qt, grid, qml

Hello I have the following Layout. But the Grid is left aligned how do I center it in the scrollview area??

```
Rectangle {
id: card
ScrollView {
    width: card.width
    height: 60
    ScrollBar.vertical.policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOff
    id: bottomMenuScrollArea
    anchors {
        bottom: parent.bottom
        bottomMargin: 20
    }

    // BOTTOM MENU
    Grid {
        id: bottomMenu
        width: card.width
        height: 60
        columns: 4
        columnSpacing: 20
        Text {
            color: Style.color.text
            text: Style.icon.home
            renderType: Text.NativeRendering
            width: 60
            height: 60
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            font {
                family: "icons"
                pixelSize: 80
            }

            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                width: parent.width + 30
                height: width

                
            }
        }
   }
 Text {
            color: Style.color.text
            text: Style.icon.home
            renderType: Text.NativeRendering
            width: 60
            height: 60
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            font {
                family: "icons"
                pixelSize: 80
            }

            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                width: parent.width + 30
                height: width

                
            }
        }
   }
 Text {
            color: Style.color.text
            text: Style.icon.home
            renderType: Text.NativeRendering
            width: 60
            height: 60
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            font {
                family: "icons"
                pixelSize: 80
            }

            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                width: parent.width + 30
                height: width

                
            }
        }
   }
 Text {
            color: Style.color.text
            text: Style.icon.home
            renderType: Text.NativeRendering
            width: 60
            height: 60
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            font {
                family: "icons"
                pixelSize: 80
            }

            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                width: parent.width + 30
                height: width

                
            }
        }
   }
  }
  }
```

Can you help me with horizontal center the grid in the scroll view area?? I tried differnt things ut was not succsesfull.
I appricate your help :)

Or is thee any better way to get scrollbars around the grid?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to place the Grid inside of an Item. Anchor the grid in the horizontal center of the Item and set the Item's width to the maximum of the ScrollView width and the Grid width. Something like this:

```
ScrollView {
    id: bottomMenuScrollArea
    Item {
        id: gridContainer
        width: Math.max(bottomMenuScrollArea.width, bottomMenu.width)
        height: bottomMenu.height
        Grid {
            id: bottomMenu
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            [...]
        }
    }
}
```